# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamOperations' available?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder

I am trying to migrate a SB 2.6 micro service to SB 3.0.2, Spring Cloud 2022.0.1 and Java 17. I am using the StreamOperations interface to send messages from within the microservice via a Rabbit binding. The class looks like;

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class AuditEventProducer {
    private final StreamOperations streamBridge;
    public final static String OUTPUT_BINDING = "AuditAnyOutputChannel";
    public AuditEventProducer(StreamOperations streamBridge) {
        this.streamBridge = streamBridge;
    }

    public void sendEvent(AbstractAuditEvent event) {
        streamBridge.send(OUTPUT_BINDING, MessageBuilder.withPayload(event).setHeader("type", "AbstractAuditEvent").build());
    }
}
```

But I see exceptions in my integration test logs and runtime logs of;

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamOperations' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1812)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
```

This is a complex Microservice so I suspect there is something in the context that is preventing the creation and injection of a StreamBridge class instance into the context.

Comment: It appears your s-c-stream autoconfiguration is not getting picked up, but without seeing your app I would not know where to begin. StreamBridge is the framework component which is always there unless the framework was not bootstrapped.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It turned out that an older version of the Spring cloud function context JAR was being used so once that was fixed all is good.